# Cannot link a library in c++ program

Tags: c++, c, linker

I have created a "**library in C**" (say "A") that uses only "**opengl32.dll and glu32.dll**".

Now, I have created two different other C++ programs (say "B" and "C") that **links the library "A"** and also **dynamically links the library "libpng" and "SDL2"**.

Now I have two possibilities:

i) **Statically link library "A"** - But this gives me error during linking saying **numerous undefined** OpenGL functions. (Okay fine up to here.)

ii) **Dynamically link library "A"** - This way both "B" and "C" programs are **compiling**.

And program "B" is **running perfectly**.

---

**"But"** when I am running program "C", it **hangs before entering** the **main function**. It is not even crashing but using 50% of CPU and running forever. I cannot debug it as it not even entering the main function most probably.

Program "C" is **running properly only** if I remove all the functions either from **library "A"** or from **library "libpng"**.

My question is what can be the **reason for this** and what are possible **work-arounds**?

N.B. - I am using "tdm-gcc32 compiler suite".

Comment: Sounds like an infinite loop running before main... so what runs before main?  Library initializations, constructors for globals... start with those (might not even be related to library "A").  There's not nearly enough information here for us to find your problem for you.

Comment: @Dmitri: All my codes in **library "A"** are written in standard C. And whatever are written in C++ in **programs "B" and "C"** do not have constructors or destructors in the user-defined classes.

Comment: Does library "A" run any initialization code when loaded?  Do any globals or locals in main() reference anything from either library when instantiated?

Comment: @Dmitri: library "A" has only functions and no global variables or initializations. Also I have only two functions png_save() and png_load() that uses "libpng".